# Sample Database Connection to SQLite Database in Cypress

Tags: database, sqlite, promise, cypress

I ran into an issue when connecting to a SQLite Database before.  Now that I figured it out, I'd like to share the solution with everyone.  Thanks.

In plugins/index.js

```
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    module.exports = (on, _config) => {
        on('task', {
             queryDb: queryTestDb,
             //wait: timeout,
        });
    };
```

Also in plugins/index.js

```
    const path='C:/Users/Mamga/TestDB/chinook.db'
    function queryTestDb(sql) {
        let db = new sqlite3.Database(path);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
            if(err) 
                reject(err); 
    
            else  {
              db.close();
              console.log(rows)
              return resolve(rows);
            }//End else
            
          });//End db.run
    
        });
    }
```

Actual Test in TaskCommandDBConnectionTest.js ///

```
    /// <reference types="Cypress" />
    describe('Task Command', () => {
      it('Should send execute something on node', () => {
        const query='select * from Persons';
        cy.task('queryDb', query).then((rows) => {
          //expect(rows).to.have.lengthOf(4);
          for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
          {
            cy.log(rows[i].FirstName + " "+ rows[i].LastName + " " + rows[i].Age)
          }
          
          });
           
      }) 
    
      })
```

Comment: The  error received was `CypressError
cy.task('queryDb') failed with the following error:

The task 'queryDb' returned undefined. You must return a value, null, or a promise that resolves to a value or null to indicate that the task was handled.`

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to a bugfix in cypress 5.3.0:
"Fixed an issue where a cy.task with no arguments passed would receive null as the first argument instead of undefined"
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#5-3-0

Comment: Hello @MrWrangler, I am happy that my question finally got an answer and I appreciate yours.  I installed Cypress 5.3.0, but the error persists.  Thank you.